# Troubleshooting Spreadsheet Form Submit Events Google

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm using Google Apps Script but I can't figure out how to troubleshoot the `onEdit(e)` method when using Spreadsheet Form Submit.

The code is pretty straight forward. Just checks a parameter in the form data and either removes it or emails someone.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var namedRange = e.namedValues;
  if (namedRange.SOME_VALUE < 3.3) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().deleteRow(sheet.getLastRow());
  } else {
    MailApp.sendEmail("none@none.na", "New Entry", e.values);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use an [installable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers) "on form submit" trigger to fire the script, and name the function something different to onEdit (so the simple "on edit" trigger is not fired as well).

Functions fired by an installable trigger allow writing to the log using Logger.log() (for example, you could invoke `Logger.log(namedRange.SOME_VALUE)` and observe the log later). As an aside, even if there was a simple trigger available for "on form submit", I don't believe Logger.log actually works for such functions.

Answer (score 0):

The onEdit function is triggered when someone manually edits the spreadsheet. For a for submit trigger, use the onSubmit() functio

Comment: OK. Thanks. But how do I troubleshoot ?

Comment: Use the Logger.log() function to dump out information and then at the end, you can write the log content to another sheet. You can get the log contents using Logger.getLog().

Comment: I'm not sure I'm answering the question "how do I troubleshoot", but to expand on answer from +Srik, you would need to _install_ an "on form submit" trigger on a function that is not named "onEdit()". (BTW is that what you mean Srik? Or is there an undocumented simple onSubmit() trigger?) For installed triggers, you should be able to use eg Logger.log(namedRange.SOME_VALUE) and view the log to troubleshoot.

Comment: @AdamL Yeah that helped. You should probably write that up as a separate answer if you want... and I'll accept

Comment: There does exist a simple onSubmit() trigger

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that can test form submission trigger functions, lifted from [How can I test a trigger function in GAS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089041/how-can-i-test-a-trigger-function-in-gas/16089067#16089067).

```
function test_onFormSubmit() {
  var dataRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange()
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var headers = data[0];
  // Start at row 1, skipping headers in row 0
  for (var row=1; row < data.length; row++) {
    var e = {};
    e.values = data[row];
    e.range = dataRange.offset(row,0,1,data[0].length);
    e.namedValues = {};
    // Loop through headers to create namedValues object
    for (var col=0; col<headers.length; col++) {
      e.namedValues[headers[col]] = e.values[col];
    }
    // Pass the simulated event to onFormSubmit
    onFormSubmit(e);
  }
}
```